# selenium webdriver exception (in firefox)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

im using selenium firefox driver 3.3.1,selenium java 3.3.0,gecko driver 0.14 and firefox 52.when i run my code "your connection is not secure" page appears but when i manually open it ,it will open without any errors 
this is the error message i got

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:127)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:93)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:42)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:325)
>       at automation.Qwik_events_uat_firefox.main(Qwik_events_uat_firefox.java:24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver)

> **acceptInsecureCerts**
>   Boolean initially set to false, indicating the session will not implicitly trust untrusted or self-signed TLS certificates on navigation.

You can initialize your FirefoxDriver like below to avoid the issue

```
    FirefoxProfile ff = new FirefoxProfile();
    ff.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ff);
```

or you can go with DesiredCapabilities like

```
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    caps.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(caps);
```

Also you should use GeckoDriver **0.15** becuase selenium recommends to do so

As per [Selenium Changelog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG)

> v3.3.1
>
> - Better support for geckodriver v0.15.0. Notably, exceptions returned   from the remote end are now unwrapped properly.